# How to override previous menu in toolbar while switching from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-menu

I am using search menu item in toolbar and while switching from one activity to another, the search button click gives output Log.d(TAG, "Default" ), rather than Log.d(TAG, "Search button Pressed" );

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.

    Log.d(TAG, "menu Item id = " + item.getItemId() );

    Log.d(TAG, "search id = " + R.id.search_emp);

    // Handle action buttons
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search_emp:

            Log.d(TAG, "Search button Pressed" );


            return true;

        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;

        default:

            Log.d(TAG, "Default" );
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

search_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/search_emp"
    android:title="@android:string/search_go"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:visible="true"/>
```

**Response**

```
05-16 16:34:11.511 3882-3882/? D/SearchListActivity: menu Item id = 2131493212
05-16 16:34:11.511 3882-3882/? D/SearchListActivity: search id = 2131493213
```

Even if I declare a new menu in my new activity it still showing previous menu. And onclick also performing same method declared in previous activity.

I am stuck here, please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call method menu.clear() just before inflate a new one. If you press back button - menu of the previous activity (or) fragment will be restored.

```kotlin
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
}
```